# how to use EHCache Configuration file in web application

Tags: java, caching, grails, ehcache

Whenever i run the application, first time it returns cacheMgr.cacheExists("myCache1") as true but after restarting the server it is giving as false. I am not able to understand the problem.

EHCacheUtilty.java

```
private static Ehcache getCache(String cacheName) throws Exception{

        if(cacheMgr == null){
            try{
            cacheMgr = CacheManager.create(new URL("http://10.10.1.133:8080/ProjectName/xml/ehcache12.xml"));
            System.out.println("cacheMgr"+cacheMgr);
                System.out.println(cacheMgr.cacheExists("myCache1"));
                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(cacheMgr.getCacheNames()));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Ehcache cache = null;
        if(cacheMgr!=null){
                //cache = cacheMgr.addCacheIfAbsent(name);
                cache = cacheMgr.getEhcache(cacheName);
        }

        return cache;
}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.sf.net/ehcache.xsd">

<diskStore path="G:\EHCacheTempMemory" />

<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true" timeToIdleSeconds="10" timeToLiveSeconds="20" diskPersistent="true" />

<cache name="myCache1"
maxElementsInMemory="500000"
maxElementsOnDisk="500000"
eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true"
timeToIdleSeconds="864000"
timeToLiveSeconds="8640000"
diskPersistent="true"
diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="8640000"
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />



</ehcache>
```

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Every time you restart the server, you will need to re-run this program (or at least the portions of it which initialize the EhCache).  Restarting the server eliminates the instance you had of it.

Comment: yes i am calling one function from my controller which will re execute this cache initialization code even though it is giving same problem but in stand alone application it is working fine.

Comment: @user2232836 Do you have any logging which proves your cache is getting reinitialized when you bounce the server?

Comment: the above sop's has given output as cacheMgr__DEFAULT__,false,[]

Comment: the problem i understood is it is not removing the old object from the JVM after restarting the server also, because IDE is not stopping the JVM so as create() method is singleton it won't allow us to create new object. how can i resolve this